# What's the meaning of "death to [someone / some group]" exactly?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Like saying "Death to the enemy!" or something like that. I understand the basic meaning, I know it's an expression one would use against his enemies, an expression of hate and hostility, but I don't understand the exact meaning.

I know it's a stupid question, but could someone explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: It's what it's says on the tin. It's not a usual construct, I've always thought of its use as a derivative of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_to_America .

Comment: Rewrite it as "I/We wish death to my/our enemy" or "I/We want my/our enemy to die". It is a stated wish, not a statement of reality.

Comment: @user3169 That's all I needed. Now I get it.

Comment: What comes to mind is the phrase used in a well-known Star Trek episode, "Death to Zeon" [**Star Trek - Patterns of Force (TV Episode 1968) - IMDb**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708442/quotes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be easier to understand the meaning if you rewrite it like:

> I/We wish death to my/our enemy.

or

> I/We want my/our enemy to die".

It is a stated wish or intention, not a statement of reality.

Comment: "We want our enemy to die" or "We want our enemy dead" may or may not only be a wish depending on circumstances. If the enemy is held under siege, it becomes more reality than just a wish.

Comment: @Peter Maybe a "wish or intention" would be better. Still it is before the fact.